# How do you make it so there is an introduction embed in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, command, bots

## For example:

Let's say that this is the intro embed for every new bot user:
[image]

Let's say that there are commands like BEG, HELP, WORK and all these many commands that this bot supports... But if you are a new bot user and you type '(prefix) beg' you WON'T beg, instead, you will get this embed shown above because you are new. And after that you can use the bot normally...

## How would you do this?

Can you use something along the lines of:

```
@client.event
async def on_new_user():
    await ctx.send(embed=introduction_embed)
```

Or is there a different way? How do I ensure that every user saw this intro embed before anything and make sure that they only see it ONCE? I am working on a discord bot using python. Would appreciate some help! Thanks so much

Comment: Can you include some code in your question? It would help if you posted code snippets of your help or welcome commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

`on_command` is run when a command is found, if I decorate it with `before_invoke` I can raise an error after sending the embed, preventing the command from running the first time for each user. It's up to you how to store the users though.

The [CommandError](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=discord%20ext%20commands%20commanderror#discord.ext.commands.CommandError) is caught and passed into `on_command_error` event.

```
registered_users = []

@bot.before_invoke
@bot.event
async def on_command(ctx):
    global registered_users
    if ctx.author not in registered_users:
        registered_users.append(ctx.author)
        embed = discord.Embed(
            color=discord.Colour.random(),
            title="WELCOME",
            description="welcome message",
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        raise commands.CommandError("Error")
```

Comment: Is `raise commands.CommandError("Error")` neccessary though?

Comment: @Hyperba If you want the first command a user invokes to be prevented, yes it is. If you remove it the welcome embed would still be sent but the command would also be run.